# Git - How to Undo an Unsync'ed Discard-All Rollback?

Tags: git

I made three commits in git but did not sync my changes. I rolled back to a local commit using the GUI and some of the commits are lost in the GUI. Can I restore those commits? I am afraid of sync'ing my current changes because I want those local commits archived in the repository.

Is it possible to recover those local commits? If so, how?

Here is an example except that my changes are not sync'ed:

[image: Commit History]
The above image is the commit history.

[image]
The above image is when I rolled back my changes[, discarded my changes, and did a `git -reset`].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the HASH code of the commit you want rollback, simply you can type `git reset --hard d513712892` to go back.

Comment: My first local commit shows up on a `git reflog`, but my second and third local commit are not shown. So, I do not have the hash code. I want to know some details on the hard reset before experimenting with it. Does it erase all of my commits after my first commit (ex. my second and third commit if they do exist somewhere locally) if I do a hard reset. (Just to clarify, my first local commit is not on Feb 27 but is after March 6 and is not sync'ed.)

Comment: Additionally, `git reset (hashcode)` does not recover all files. Does a hard reset will achieve this?

Comment: @swtdrgn your first image shows all the HASH code. `--hard` options  is used for reseting to one commit, and reseting the index and working tree.

Comment: but those commits are not the commits that I want to reset to. I am referring to those that I have not sync'ed.

Comment: @swtdrgn ok, if you can show a commit line and the output of `git reflog`, we may know better what exactly commit you want to rollback.

Comment: It was not shown on the `git reflog`. I just found out about `git fsck --lost-found` and my last commit can be found using that command line. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @swtdrgn whatever if you can find the HASH code, you can simply rollback with this command.